# Combinatorial proof of $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{n \choose 2}^{-1}=1$

Tags: combinatorics

I was wondering if there is any "combinatorial proof" to the fact that:
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n \choose 2}}=1$$
Perhaps for example it could be seen as the distribution of some natural experiment.

Comment: Although not a combinatorial proof, it may help to relate it to other sums $$\sum_{n \ge 3} \frac{1}{n \choose 2} = 2! \sum_{n \ge 3} \frac{(n - 2)!}{n!} = 2! \sum_{n \ge 3} \frac{1}{n(n - 1)} = 2! \sum_{n \ge 3} \left( \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n} \right)$$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2938484/sum-of-reciprocals-of-triangular-numbers-and-calculus?noredirect=1).

Comment: Here's a Proof Without Words for the identity (starting from $n=2$): https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Roger_B36528._Nelsen_Vol_64_No_3.pdf

Comment: A (silly) probabilistic proof: a standard exponential random variable $X$ almost surely falls into one and only one of the intervals $I_n=[\log{\frac{n-1}2},\log{\frac n2}[$ for some $n\ge3$ (because these form a partition of $[0,\infty[$), and $\Bbb P(X\in I_n)=\frac1{\binom n2}$.

Comment: @Matthew Cassell  You almost proved it. $\sum_{n\ge3}^m\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+...-\frac{1}{m}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{m}$. When $m$ goes to $\infty$, $\sum_{n\ge3}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, $2!\sum_{n\ge3}\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\sum_{n\ge3}\frac{1}{n \choose 2}=1$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks, it seems someone else already had the same idea, unfortunately no combinatorial interpretation there as well.